# order the meta query results by 2 custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query

I have a custom post type 'brewery', I want to fetch results by 2 custom fields. The desired result is to get all posts with highest review rating (value is in decimal like 4.2 or 4.8) and if few posts have same review rating then I want to sort the results by review count (value is numeric and can be any number like 5, 400 or even 2500).

Example:

Post 1 -> Review rating = 4.8 & Review Count = 2500

Post 2 -> Review rating = 4.8 & Review Count = 1500

Post 3 -> Review rating = 4.5 & Review Count = 3500

Post 4 -> Review rating = 4.5 & Review Count = 3000

The below code is sorting the results only by review rating and not by review count. Can somene please let me know what is wrong with the code or if there is something that I am missing?

Also, please find the attached screenshot of results.

[image]

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'brewery',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'review_rating_meta' => array(
            'key' => 'review_rating',
        ),
        'reveiw_count_meta' => array(
            'key' => 'reveiw_count',
        ),
    ),

    'orderby'    => array(
        'review_rating_meta' => 'DESC',
        'reveiw_count_meta' => 'DESC',
    )
);
```

Comment: Perhaps this misspelling: "reveiw"

Comment: @shanebp yes I know, don't worry its the same spelled in the backend as well.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `relation` in `meta_query` .
I think this will work:

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'brewery',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'meta_query'     => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        'review_rating_meta' => array(
            'key' => 'review_rating',
        ),
        'reveiw_count_meta' => array(
            'key' => 'reveiw_count',
        ),
    ),

    'orderby'    => array(
        'review_rating_meta' => 'DESC',
        'reveiw_count_meta' => 'DESC',
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Siavash ! I tried with the relation but that does not work.